# Why I can not use CURL in my namespaces?

Tags: php, curl

Just moved my project to another PC - almost the same environment: Windows 10, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.0.3, but suddenly Curl doesn't want to initialize, just like it is not installed (**but extension is loaded**).

I found out thet it needs backslashes like \curl_init() or \CURLOPT_RERURNTRANSFER - but I'm wondering why it was working ok without this on another PC with same environment? And how to get it working without this damn backslashes on the new PC?

```
public function getCurl(int $instantiate, array $params = [], string $url = ''): CUrl
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift($args);
    return self::handleCaching($instantiate, 'asoft\\CUrl', ...$args);
}

protected function handleCaching(int $instantiate, string $class, ...$args)
{

    switch ($instantiate) {
        case self::NEW_INSTANCE:
            return new $class(...$args);
        case self::CACHED_INSTANCE:
            if (!array_key_exists($class, self::$cache)) {
                self::$cache[$class] = new $class(...$args);
            }
            return self::$cache[$class];
    }

    throw new EngineError('Wrong value for instantiating type: $instance.');
}
```

> Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER - assumed
>   'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\audiophilesoft.local\vendor\asoft\PersistenceFactory.php:185Notice:
>   Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER - assumed
>   'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\audiophilesoft.local\vendor\asoft\PersistenceFactory.php:185
>
> Error: Call to undefined function asoft\curl_init() in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\audiophilesoft.local\vendor\asoft\CUrl.php:27 Stack
>   trace:

Line 185 is "protected function handleCaching(..." As you see,absolutely no constants there.

I have this problem only on new PC.

Comment: Maybe you should post some of your code

Comment: Done. As you see, I use caching.

Comment: Copying Apache from old to new PC has solved the problem. But I still have no idea why it was happening...

Comment: I could guess that slash can helps. Will be prepending all curl function and constants with '\' so hard, as I imagine (sometimes it's really hard not to forget or miss somewhere)? And idk will it helps or not, just guessing... It seems that PHP7 searching inside of current scope. :-/ So the old machine also has PHP7? Strange...

Comment: @ Wizard , very strange. And also simple instantiating works well in any namespace... So the problem is only with such PersistanceFactory as I use - with cachiing and dynamical calss name. The most strange thing is that changing Apache installation (not PHP) has helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, the problem was that PHP and/or Apache folder was not in Windows include path.